# .NET Core 6 - react to events

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, events

Events noob here.
I have an WPF app (.NET 6) that calls a method in a class library (class A).
This method then calls a method in another class, class B (this may be in the same class library or in another), that does a long process in a loop.

So in WPF app, i have an instance of A, and in A I have an instance of B.

In class B I have an event that fires in each iteration of the loop, and then in A I react to this event.

What would be the correct way to notify the WPF app from A whenever the event (that is in B) fires? (WPF can not suscribe to that event that B fires, as in WPF I only have an instance of A, not B)

I guess I could have an event in A, that WPF can see, and then whenever B event fires, I could capture it in A and then fire its own event that WPF can suscribe to... but is this a correct way of doing this?

note - all methods in A and B are async, and in WPF app I am calling the method in class A with Task.Run()

Comment: Take a look at the model-view-view model (MVVM) architectural pattern. B would be a model class, while A would be a view model class. Communication from view model to view is typically done by data binding. The view would bind to a property in class A that would repeatedly be updated whenever the event in class B is fired. [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0).